# c# nested loops- get distinct elements from List (without Linq)

Tags: c#, list, loops, nested

If I have a List which contains some possibly duplicated string elements e.g. `"dog","cat","dog","cow","cow","owl"`.
I need to get the distinct elements from that list ( so I need to write the list of all elements without repetitive ones i.e. `"dog","cat","cow","owl"`).
There must be a way how to use it with nested loops but I got stuck on something below:

```
IList<string> animals;
int a = animals.Count();
for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
    foreach (string animal in animals)
    {
     if (animals[i+1] != animals[i])
      {
       Console.WriteLine(animals[i]);
       }
    }
  }
```

This is something close but it's not the correct one.
Perhaps the nested inner loop should be "while" or another "for".
Appreciate any tip on above.
Thanks!

Comment: The issue with your approach isn't the nested loops...it is that you are printing instead of adding the uniques to your tracking collection.  Try to visualize what is happening when you loop through each of the collections.  In the first loop, you want to interact with every animal.  In the second loop, you should be checking for a match in the animals collection and, if there isn't one, you want to track it as a unique element.  You can't actually write to console until you've inspected every element first.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) This class is similar to a List but doesn't allow duplicates

```
IList<string> animals = new List<string> {"Lion", "Wolf", "Tiger", "Dog", "Cat", "Lion", "Tiger"};
HashSet<string> uniques = new HashSet<string>(animals);
foreach(animal in uniques)
   Console.WriteLIne(animal);
```

If you want to use a loop you could simplify your code using a second list where you will store unique values and while at it you can also avoid false uniqueness when the only difference is case upper or lower in the animal name

```
IList<string> animals = new List<string> {"Lion", "Wolf", "Tiger", "Dog", "Cat", "Lion", "tiger"};
List<string> uniques = new List<string>();
foreach (string animal in animals)
{
    if (!SearchCaseInsensitive(uniques, animal))
        uniques.Add(animal);
}
foreach(string animal in uniques)
    Console.WriteLine(animal);


bool SearchCaseInsensitive(List<string> source, string search)
{
    string lowerCaseSearch = search.ToLower();
    foreach(string animal in source)
        if(animal.ToLower() == lowerCaseSearch)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly the easiest way to solve the problem, it doesn't use explicit nested loops and it doesn't help the OP understand what the nested loop is supposed to accomplish.  This seems like a homework problem and this answer doesn't help the OP understand what is wrong with their original approach.

Comment: Of course you are correct @DavidL This is not a solution if you want to learn how you should work with loops and your comment is very educative. Other answers here have a correct loop example, but they fail as mine in handling upper and lower case

Comment: HashSet works as well . I was asked tto do int in traditional way without using Linq so I guess that the answer from KnightFighter is a bit more suitable to what I needed. But HashSet is good and  usefull as well . Thank you.

Comment: Yes but consider that "Lion" and "lion" are two different animals in every solution posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would to use a loop to iterate the elements and add to another collection, each time you encounter a new one. For example,

```
var unique = new List<string>();
foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    if(!unique.Contains(animal))
    {
        unique.Add(animal);
    }
}

foreach(var item in unique)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

If you collection contains too many elements, a Dictionary with a faster look up might be a better solution than List. For example

```
var unique = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    if(!unique.ContainsKey(animal))
    {
        unique.Add(animal,1);
    }
}

foreach(var item in unique)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend using HashSet.

```
HashSet<string> uniqueAnimals = new HashSet<string>(animals);
```

Comment: HashSet works as well . I was asked tto do int in traditional way without using Linq so I guess that the answer from KnightFighter is a bit more suitable to what I needed. But HashSet is good and  usefull as well . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> animals new List<string> {"dog","cat","dog","cow","cow","owl"};  // your animals list

List<string> sorted = new List<string>();
foreach(string animal in animals)
{
     if (!sorted.Contains(animal))
      {
        sorted.Add(animal);
      }
}
```

Comment: @kalka79 welcome. Best way to thanks by accepting answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another `HashSet<string>` solution:

```
HashSet<string> unique = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var animal in animals)
  if (unique.Add(animal))
    Console.WriteLine(animal);
```